# regex pattern to find & which appears in text but not in entities?

Tags: regex, html-entities

I need to match `&` which is present in plain text but it should not capture the `&` from entities like `&#x69;`

e.g.,

```
hi this is a plain text containing & and the entity &#x45; , &#65286; and &amp;
```

In the above text I should find only `&` which is in text--i.e., coming after `containing`.
I tried this pattern `&[^#x]*` but I couldn't get all matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stolen regex to match HTML entities from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311890/471214) combined with look-aheads:

```
&(?!(amp|apos|gt|lt|nbsp|quot|bull|hellip|[lr][ds]quo|[mn]dash|permil|
     \#[1-9]\d{1,3}|[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]+);)
```

#### Shortened:

```java
&(?!(\#[1-9]\d{1,3}|[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]+);)
```

#### Explained:

We want to match `&` but not `&123;` etc.

```java
&                 // match an ampersand
(                 // group starts
    ?!            // negative look-ahead (don't match '&' if this group matches)
    (\#[1-9]\d{1,3}|[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]+); // regex to match HTML entity after '&'
)                 // group ends
```

Answer (score 0):

With `[^#x]` you match all **single** characters that are not '#' nor 'x'.
What you probably want is `&[^#][^x]`. If you may have '&' at the end of string or the sting may be shorter than 3 characters, you have to consider these cases in addition.

PS: Escaping depends on your actual flavour of regex.

**EDIT**

For the case of `&amp` (and all other HTML entities, e.g. `!` = `&excl;`) you can simply provied alternatives, e.g.
`&([^#][^x])|([^a][^m][^p])|([^e][^x][^c][^l])`

If your flavour of regex allows look-ahead assertion, it is easier to use `&(?!(#x|amp|excl))` etc.

Comment: thanks for reply.. but what about the third case i.e., &amp; i dont want to catch this also