# Dart sanitize international text

Tags: internationalization, dart, dart-html

How best do I sanitize text like

```
abc&#39; a>b<c & a<b>c
```

converting/displaying

```
abc&#39; a&gt;b&le;c &amp; a&le;b&gt;c
```

or in clear text

```
abc' a>b<c & a<b>c
```

so that I can use it via

```
myDiv.innerHtml=...   or
myDiv.setInnerHtml(..., myValidator, mySantitizer);
```

A text assignment `myDiv.text=...` converts all & and <> eliminating the valid apostrophe `&#39;` - the **HtmlEscape**.convert(..) class/method also converts all & in all HtmlEscapeMode's.

Could write my own Sanitizer, but hope that I overlooked some standard library/call.

Comment: So you want to partially sanitize text?  Why do you want to convert some characters to html entities, but not others?  Why does the input text contain some "unsanitized" characters, but not others?

Comment: Translations, e.g. from Google Translate and others usually contain certain html codes. My current workaround is to convert it to unicode, so that I I can assign it to myElement **.text** .  I hoped that I either overlooked such a library call - or that there is a solution for assignments to myElement **.innerHtml**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DartPad Link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/750a3730a485fd085e3e)

[RexExp for HTML Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310572/regex-in-php-to-match-that-arent-html-entities)

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String htmlStr = r'abc&#39; a>b<c & a<b>' * 3;
  var reg = new RegExp(r"(.*?)(&#[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]+;)|(.*)");
  List<Match> matchs = reg.allMatches(htmlStr);
  var resStr = '';
  matchs.forEach((m) {
    var g1 = m.group(1);
    var g2 = m.group(2);
    var g3 = m.group(3);
    g1 = HTML_ESCAPE.convert(g1 == null ? '' : g1);
    g2 = g2 == null ? '' : g2;
    g3 = HTML_ESCAPE.convert(g3 == null ? '' : g3);
    resStr += g1 + g2 + g3;
  });
  print(resStr);
  document.body.setInnerHtml(resStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, I realized that using Validators or HtmlEscape/Mode  was not the best way to solve the problem.

The original problem was that translation engines use &#39; for the apostrophe - probably to not confuse it with the misuse of apostrophe as a single quote.

In summary, the best solution is to replace &#39; with the correct unicode character for the apostrophe, which is actually

- NOT "\u{0027}" = ' = unicode apostrophe - displayed as (straight) single quote
- NOT "\u{2019}" = ’ = unicode right single (curly) quotation mark - see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm
- but "\u{02BC}" = ʼ = the modifier letter apostrophe - displayed like a curly quote - see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02BC/index.htm

The (correct) apostrophe U+0027 &#39; is misliked is as character fonts print it (incorrectly) straight - which graphic guys really hate - like the straight ".

With that, you can assign the translated text to element.text and if it contains problematic characters, they are escaped automatically by Dart - and rendered just fine.